# Type Quit to Quit C Program

Tags: c, string

I was wondering what the problem with my program is. I can't get the program to exit when I type quit.
Here is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char string[200];

    printf("Enter a bunch of words: ");
    do
    {
        scanf("%[^\n]c", string);


    }while(strcmp(string,"quit")!=0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you required by specifications on an exercise you're doing to use `scanf`? If not, I'd recommend another method.

Comment: @GovindParmar yeah, I have to use scanf, we can't use anything we haven't learned yet.

Comment: @UnholySheep no it isn't. it is a scanning format for a string that consists of any characters besides newline, followed by literal `c`.

Comment: Why are you using `scanf("%[^\n]c", string);` instead of `fgets (string, sizeof string, stdin)`?  (and then `strncmp (string, "quit", 4);`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This is part of a school assignment and I can't use anything that hasn't been taught yet, so I have to use scanf

Comment: Then what about `scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", string);`? (the `'*'` being the *assignment suppression operator* allowing the next character (e.g. `%c`) to be read and disregarded without affecting the returned *conversion count*. (which you should be checking `if (scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", string) != 1) { /* handle error */ }`)

Comment: Hi @anon. You should explain what you think `"%[^\n]c"` means.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: It doesn't really mean that. The `%[^\n]` will leave the `\n` in the input stream. So, the next character cannot be a literal `c`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin hmmm, I really appreciate the fix, thank you so much but again I haven't been taught that technique, so I have to do it in a simpler way. Is there a way maybe to do while(1) and then inside the loop do if(strcmp(string,"quit")!=0) break; I've tried so many permutations, I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: @jxh of course it is impossible to match the entire format, but that's what it means.

Comment: @jxh it allows spaces in between words. If I didn't have it then it would stop at the first space, I think.

Comment: @anon: But what did you want to accomplish with the trailing `c`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two biggest problems are two of the most common problems that plague new C programmers with their use of `scanf`:

> 1. You are using an incorrect format string; and
> 2. You fail to check the return of `scanf`.

Let's address first things first:

```
scanf("%[^\n]c", string);
```

Your format string `"%[^\n]c"` uses the *character-class* format specifier `"%[...]"` to read the text for `string`. It is then followed by `"c"` -- which will only match a literal `'c'` at the end of your input string. That cannot happen as written because `"%[^\n]"` will read all characters that are not the `'\n'` leaving only the `'\n'` to be read -- *which does NOT match* `'c'`.

Further, the `"%[...]"` specifier along with the `"%c"` specifier do NOT *consume leading whitespace* (the `'\n'` being whitespace). So having left the `'\n'` unread in `stdin` your next call to `scanf` fails because `"%[^\n]"` will not read the `'\n'` and it doesn't match `'c'` leading to a *matching failure*, the `'\n'` remains unread in `stdin` and things quickly spiral out of control.

To solve all of the problems you need to remember `(2.)` above and also use a *field-width* modifier to protect the array bounds of `string`, and you should then read and *Save* the character following those extracted and put in `string` to ***validate*** a complete line of input was read -- and if not, it is ***your responsibility*** to remove any excess characters that remain in `stdin` ***before*** attempting your next read.

For starters, you can use a properly limited *format string* that includes a `space` at the beginning that will cause `scanf` to discard all leading whitespace, e.g.

```
    " %199[^\n]%c"
```

Note above the final character will be saved, ***two*** conversions will take place, so you will need a character variable to handle result of the final conversion specifier, e.g.

```
    do {
        char c;     /* final character read */
        int retn;   /* variable to save scanf return */
        /* prompt */
        fputs ("Enter a bunch of words ('quit' exits): ", stdout);
        /* read saving scanf return */
        retn = scanf (" %199[^\n]%c", string, &c);
```

(**note:** the prompt has been moved within the `do {...} while (..);` loop)

Next ***you*** are responsible for checking the ***return*** of `scanf` *every time*. You must handle ***three conditions***

1. `(return == EOF)` the user canceling input by generating a manual `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or on windows <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd>);
2. `(return < expected No. of conversions)`, you must handle the *matching* or *input* failure and you must account for every character that may be left in your input buffer. (generally you will scan forward in the input buffer until a `'\n'` or `EOF` is found discarding any extraneous characters that remain, see the `empty_stdin()` function in the example); and
3. `(return == expected No. of conversions)` indicating a successful read -- it is then up to you to check whether the input meets any additional criteria (e.g. positive integer, positive floating-point, etc..).

Putting it altogether, you could handle you loop reading with `scanf` and looking for `"quit"` as the keyword prompting exit as follows:

```
    do {
        char c;     /* final character read */
        int retn;   /* variable to save scanf return */
        /* prompt */
        fputs ("Enter a bunch of words ('quit' exits): ", stdout);
        /* read saving scanf return */
        retn = scanf (" %199[^\n]%c", string, &c);
        if (retn == EOF) {      /* check the return against EOF */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            return 0;
        }
        else if (retn < 2) {    /* checking both string and c read */
            fputs ("input failure.\n", stderr);
            empty_stdin();
        }
        else if (c != '\n') {   /* check c is '\n', else string too long */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: input exceeds %d characters.\n",
                    MAXC - 1);
            empty_stdin();
        }
        else    /* good input, output string */
            printf ("string: %s\n", string);

    } while (strcmp (string,"quit") != 0);
```

Finally do NOT use *magic-numbers* in your code (`200` is a *magic-number*). Instead, if you need a *constant*, `#define` one (or more). The only place you must hard-code numbers are for example the `scanf` *field-width* modifier -- which cannot use a variable, Macro or named constant. That is one exception to the rule. Likewise, do NOT hardcode filenames or paths. All functions take arguments, even `main()`, pass the needed information to your program.

Putting it altogether, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 200    /* constant - maximum characters in string */ 

void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
        c = getchar();
}

int main (void) {

    char string[MAXC];    /* use constants for array bounds */

    do {
        char c;     /* final character read */
        int retn;   /* variable to save scanf return */
        /* prompt */
        fputs ("Enter a bunch of words ('quit' exits): ", stdout);
        /* read saving scanf return */
        retn = scanf (" %199[^\n]%c", string, &c);
        if (retn == EOF) {      /* check the return against EOF */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            return 0;
        }
        else if (retn < 2) {    /* checking both string and c read */
            fputs ("input failure.\n", stderr);
            empty_stdin();
        }
        else if (c != '\n') {   /* check c is '\n', else string too long */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: input exceeds %d characters.\n",
                    MAXC - 1);
            empty_stdin();
        }
        else    /* good input, output string */
            printf ("string: %s\n", string);

    } while (strcmp (string,"quit") != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_string_quit
Enter a bunch of words ('quit' exits): Hello
string: Hello
Enter a bunch of words ('quit' exits): My dog has fleas and my cat has none.
string: My dog has fleas and my cat has none.
Enter a bunch of words ('quit' exits): quit
string: quit
```

Generating a manual `EOF` with <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windoze):

```
$ ./bin/scanf_string_quit
Enter a bunch of words ('quit' exits): Hello
string: Hello
Enter a bunch of words ('quit' exits): (user canceled input)
```

Resetting `MAXC` to `20` and the *field width* modifier to `scanf` to `19` you can check the handling of lines that are too long, e.g. the first input fits, the second is too long:

```
$ ./bin/scanf_string_quit
Enter a bunch of words ('quit' exits): my dog has fleas and my cat has none.
warning: input exceeds 19 characters.
Enter a bunch of words ('quit' exits): 1234567890123456789
string: 1234567890123456789
Enter a bunch of words ('quit' exits): 12345678901234567890
warning: input exceeds 19 characters.
Enter a bunch of words ('quit' exits): quit
string: quit
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much, I really appreciate all the details. I've followed advice from a you and another user and my program quits once I type in quit. However, this has lead to a new problem since I didn't describe the purpose of my program so you guys answered what you assumed my program wanted, I'm going to post a new question that explains more thoroughly what I want to do once I have the program quit.

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this acceptable?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char string[200] = {0};

    printf("Enter a bunch of words: ");
    do {
        memset(string, 0, 200);
        scanf("%s", string);
    } while (strcmp(string, "quit") != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

You haven't explained exactly what you intend to do with string, so it's difficult to give an answer. However, one thing to note is that you have to either do something to `string` (I've just zeroed it out here) in order for `strcmp` to recognize "quit", or scan substrings of `string`, because if everything is always appended then your string will be "(...)quit" which strcmp won't recognize as "quit".

As a side note, always initialize your arrays or bad things could happen.

Comment: I can't use memset, I haven't learned that yet in class :/. BUT, I initialized the array like you suggested and it worked without memset. Thank you so much!

Comment: @anon You can also just set every index in `string` to 0 using a `for` loop, but the task probably requires more than just that. Glad it was of use.

Comment: @Joshua I was always partial to Integer Overflow Man, he was my favourite super hero. It's true that it runs that danger, but anon hasn't really specified the boundaries of the task he's given so I was just trying to give the simplest proposal to something that would work with the issue he seemed to be having. Memory safety didn't seem to be a part of that.

Answer (score 0):

Given the sparse explanation you have provided, the most straightforward change may be to modify your scan string to swallow the `\n` instead of a theoretical `c` which is actually impossible:

```
        scanf("%[^\n]\n", string);
```

To prevent buffer overflow, you should specify how much room your buffer has to store input:

```
        scanf("%199[^\n]\n", string);
```

This is safe so long as you know the input will never surpass 199 characters. But, this is a weak assumption both in theory and practice. The characters past the 199 saved will get scanned as your next word on the next iteration, which would allow your program to quit unexpectedly if the input was 199 `.`s followed by the word `quit`. You need a more reliable way to scan to the rest of the line and discard it before reading the next line.

You might be tempted to use another `%[...]` to capture the extra characters like this:

```
        scanf("%199[^\n]%*[^\n]\n", string);
```

However, this will fail for the common case where the input is less or equal to 199 characters. This is because `scanf` will fail if the conversion results in empty input. So, the `\n` will remain jammed in the input.

If you are limited to using `scanf`, then you will need to split the scanning into separate `scanf` calls so that the error and non-error scan for the rest of the line can be treated as the same outcome, leading to a second `scanf` to swallow the newline itself.

```
        scanf("%199[^\n]%*[^\n]", string);
        scanf("\n");
```